# Favoritos android studio sin base de datos

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una lista con una serie de radios en streaming y tengo que añadir un botón de favoritos (El típico corazón) y al pulsarlo, que esa radio se que se guarde en otra activity (Favoritos) y cuando salga y entre de la aplicación que se guarden los cambios pero estoy perdido y no encuentro solución.

Tengo otra actividad que al pulsar en la radio se abre un reproductor, pero no me deja ponerlo. Pero creo que para lo de favoritos no necesito publicar esa actividad.

Adjunto lo que tengo hasta ahora...

### Principal

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Principal extends AppCompatActivity {

//private Typeface comicBook;

ListView lista;
private MediaPlayer player;

//Vector para añadir los datos de las radios
String [][] datos = {
        {"RadioAnime","Radio Anime station online listen anime music streaming radio anime radio musica anime openings, endings la mejor radio para el j-pop y k-pop.","http://radioanime.radioca.st/stream"},//0
        {"AnimeRadio UK", "Anime Radio UK is the only official radio station dedicated to bringing you the very best music from Japanese anime, video games, film, Jpop, Jrock and everything else inbetween.","http://149.255.59.164:8049/stream"},
        {"Anime Blast Radio", "The newest place for anime music, Anime Blast Radio - Anime Internet Radio. The place for the best streaming anime music.","http://192.99.8.170:6110/stream?icy=http"},
        {"Chiru.no", "Anime Japanese Jpop Video Game","http://142.4.209.132:8000/stream"},
        {"Extreme Anime Radio", "Extreme Anime Radio, Your Anime & J-Pop Radio Station, Playing best top Japanese jpop jrock video game music online, streaming.","http://174.37.159.206:8052/stream?icy=http"},
        {"Otaku Music Radio", "Emisora de radio con la mejor música otaku, j-rock, j-pop..., y las noticias del mundo japonés, del manga y del anime.","http://149.56.240.65:20068/stream?icy=http"},//5
        {"Akihabara Radio", "Música Asiatica, OST de Anime y Covers.","http://176.31.241.17:8814/mp3?icy=http"},
        {"Blue Anime Ivana","Welcome to my Anime Radio Station where you will be able to hear a large amount of Anime music from over 500 different Anime! ","http://listen.radionomy.com:80/BlueAnimeIvana?icy=http"},
        {"AnimeNexus","Radio Anime Nexus, La mejor radio anime de Latinoamérica, J-Pop y J-Rock, con Podcast informativos, Revista otaku y mucho mas.","http://radio.animenexus.mx:8000/animenexus"},
        {"Anime-extremo","Esta radio esta dedicada a todos los fans del anime, aquí se comparten Animes por diversos servidores (Google Drive, Mega, 1fichier, etc.) en HD y BD.","http://192.99.17.12:4708/stream"},
        {"BaKaRadio.Net","La música japonesa, Jpop, Jrock, Anime, Game y muchos más. Escucha música anime en línea las 24 horas.","http://144.217.203.184:8398/stream"},//10
        {"McAnimeRadio","Mc Radio dónde escuchamos nuestra musica favorita ¡Como Tú!","http://198.105.216.204/proxy/mcradio?mp=/;"}

};

//vector para añadir los logos de las emisoras, tiene que estar cada logo en el orden como arriba
int[] datosImg = {R.drawable.logo0,R.drawable.logo1,R.drawable.logo2,R.drawable.logo3,R.drawable.logo4,R.drawable.logo5,
        R.drawable.logo6,R.drawable.logo7,R.drawable.logo8,R.drawable.logo9,R.drawable.logo10,R.drawable.logo11};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

    //String fuente2 = "fuentes/ComicBook.otf";
    //this.comicBook = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),fuente2);

    lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvlista);
    //lista.setFocusable(false);


    //instanciamos y le mandamos los datos
    lista.setAdapter(new Adaptador(this, datos, datosImg));



    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent visorRadio = new Intent(Principal.this, PantallaRadio.class);
            visorRadio.putExtra("TIT", datos[position][0]);
            visorRadio.putExtra("URL", datos[position][2]);

            visorRadio.putExtra("IMG", datosImg[position]);

            startActivity(visorRadio);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);


        }
    });
}
}
```

### Adaptador

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {//esta clase es para asociar los elementos, la que va a controlar nuestro adaptador
private Typeface comicBook;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;//Para instanciar el archivo de diseño

Context contexto;//el entorno de la app, todo que utiliza para generar el adaptador
String [][] datos;//matriz para almacenar los datos de la principal
int [] datosImg;//igual que arriba

//Generamos el constructor
public Adaptador (Context contexto, String [][] datos, int [] datosImg){
    this.contexto = contexto;
    this.datos = datos;
    this.datosImg = datosImg;
    //declaramos el inflater y lo inicializamos, con esto instanciamos el xml
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)contexto.getSystemService(contexto.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    comicBook = Typeface.createFromAsset(contexto.getAssets(), "fuentes/ComicBook.otf");

}

@Override
public View getView(int i, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final View vista  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista, null);

    TextView titulo = (TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
    TextView descripcion = (TextView)vista.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion);
    ImageView imagen = (ImageView)vista.findViewById(R.id.ivImagen);
    //RatingBar calificacion = (RatingBar)vista.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarRadio);


    titulo.setText(datos[i][0]);
    titulo.setTypeface(comicBook);
    descripcion.setText(datos[i][1]);
    descripcion.setTypeface(comicBook);
    //calificacion.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(datos[i][1]));
    imagen.setImageResource(datosImg[i]);


    imagen.setTag(i);
    imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(contexto);
            ImageView img = new ImageView(contexto);
            img.setImageResource( datosImg[(Integer)v.getTag()]);
            dialog.addContentView(img,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(500,500));
            dialog.show();
            //Intent visorImagen = new Intent(contexto, VisorImagen.class);
            //visorImagen.putExtra("IMG", datosImg[(Integer)v.getTag()]);
            //contexto.startActivity(visorImagen);
        }
    });




    return vista;
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return datos.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


}
```

### elemento_lista.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="6dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="116dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="102dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitulo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.037" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivImagen"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.376"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.529"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDescripcion"
    android:layout_width="264dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:alpha=".7"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline7"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

### activity_principal.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvlista"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Es mi primer post, si tengo que adjuntar algo más avisarme.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa `SharedPreferences` para guardar valores y que se recuperen al volver a entrar. Es lo que se usa por ejemplo para recordar usuarios, recordar personalizaciones del usuario etc...

Funciona asociando informacion a una clave, por ejemplo

```
("numero de casas","seis")
("coches rojos", 7)

//La declaras

private SharedPreferences shared;

//La instancias, si no existe, se crea, si existe, se recupera.
shared = getSharedPreferences("shared", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Para meter datos en el share necesitas un editor, lo instancias, metes datos
que pueden ser de tipo int, string...y haces commit, importante!

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
editor.putString("clave","valor");
editor.commit();
```

Tambien puedes quitarlos

```
editor.remove("clave");
```

Para recuperarlas debes buscarlas por la clave, y en caso de que no exista, devolver uno por defecto

```
share.getString("clave","defecto");
```

Comment: Y como hago para guardar todos los datos que me devuelve en la lista, podrías echarme una mano en un ejemplo más centrado de mi app? Gracias de nuevo

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza @Hach3, te he dejado en Drive un pequeño proyecto que te dará una idea de como se usa.

(https://drive.google.com/open?id=14QyELVMah4rmZHCFQ3rKhfsSbJoHGKdq)

Comment: Ya lo tengo y va de maravilla aunque me volví un poco loco, pero ya funciona! Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Me alegro que te funcionase, un saludo!